# How to get all CSS style properties from / by the classname? How to find a class in the stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get all CSS properties for each classes which matched a element.

I have the classnames of my element from

```
this.className
```

How can I now get all the css-styles for each classname?

Maybe I must compare or search in the stylesheets?

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
```

I only know the way to get the css-styles for the element but not for the classname.

Thanks for helping.

Update
This is no duplicate, I'm not looking for all kind of CSS properties. I looking specially only for the properties of a css-class, so I think it's a unique question.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: there is no more code, its a generaly question how its possible to get the style-properties of a css-class from the stylesheets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: This is no duclicate, i'm not looking for all kind of css properties. I looking specially only for the properties of a css-class, so i think it's a unique question

Comment: Yes, `document.styleSheets` is the right keyword. You will have to go through all stylesheets, go through their rules, and see if the selector matches what you are looking for. (Having to deal with order and specificity might come on top of that.)

Comment: If i trie "classes=sheets[i].cssRules;" i get a "SecurityError: The operation is insecure."

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAttribute` to get the styles. **This works for inline css only**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(e=>console.log(e.getAttribute('style')))
```

```html
<div class="a" style="color:red"></div>
<div class="a" style="color:blue"></div>
```

Comment: Yes thats the problem, i need to work with the styles from the stylesheet not from the inlinestyle. I must compare later inlinestyle with style of style-sheets.

Comment: Check this out    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: i know this, but it helps me not much. I need a way only for getting the properties of one class not all possible styles...

Answer (score 1):

`document.styleSheets[index]` from this object you can get needed information for CSS class. You have to just write a function which will do a search within

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules or document.styleSheets[0].rules by checking
```

selectorText is equal to needed class name and then get that objects cssText or style.cssText property.

Comment: yes i think that could be the way, can i check each stylesheet in a kind like that if(stylesheet[0].cssRules[classname_i_looking_for].length)...?

Comment: Just check both of document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules properties in loop for selectorText equality to your css class name and then get same objects cssText property for declared css properties

Comment: mmh, could you make me s small example, my tries failed